# TF270016 Error publishing access denied even with correct permissions on drop folder TFS 2013

Tags: tfs

I am having trouble solving an access denied problem. I've gone through so many posts trying to find a solution and just can't seem to figure out what is going on. I am new to setting up a build server, but I dug through as many sites and instructions as I could to try to understand how to do it. We are using TFS 2013 Express. I installed the Build server components, setting up a Build Controller and a Build agent. Originally I used the default Network Service account but when I ran into some issues, I decided to set up a domain user account for the build service. I removed the controller and then recreated a new controller and agent using the domain user account.

When I try to build a project--my first build definition--I get the following error:

> Exception Message: TF270016: An error occurred publishing log files
>   from 'C:\Builds\5\XYZ\Client\src\DEV\XYZ.log' to
>   '\myserver\Builds\Client\Client_20141212.4\logs'. Details: Access
>   to the path '\myserver\Builds\Client\Client_20141212.4\logs' is
>   denied. (type PublishLogFileException) Exception Stack Trace:    at
>   System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) 
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
>
> Inner Exception Details:
>
> Exception Message: Access to the path
>   '\myserver\Builds\Client\Client_20141212.4\logs' is denied. (type
>   UnauthorizedAccessException) Exception Stack Trace:    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String
>   path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean
>   checkHost)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.CopyFile(String oldPath,
>   String newPath, Boolean overwriteExisting)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.WindowsDropProvider.CopyDirectory(String
>   sourceDirectory, String targetDirectory)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.WindowsDropProvider.CopyDirectory(String
>   sourceDirectory, String targetDirectory, String[] renameIfExists)
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.PublishLogFile.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context)

I know that it appears evident that it's a permissions issue. However, I have verified that the user account I have set up my build service to use has permissions to the \myserver\Builds share. I can log in as that user, connect to the share, and create, edit and delete files. So I'm just not sure what I'm missing here or why I'm still getting the access denied error.

I'd love some feedback other than the typical 'you just need to give permissions to your drop folder to your build service account'.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this with a customer. The solution in my case was that the build drop location can't be a friendly DNS name.

For example, our server's name was GXDPLTFSBLD1P. We set up a DNS alias for the server to "tfsbuild".

When the build drop location in the build definition was set to `\\tfsbuild\drops`, we got that error.

When we changed it to `\\GXDPLTFSBLD1P\drops`, it went away.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In this case, we do not have an alias--the servername 'myserver' in the posted stack trace is the actual server name.